# php ldap retrieve ou value of dn

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying below code to get the value as `ou=grp1` from

`dn: uid=john,ou=grp1,ou=people,dc=site,dc=com` , but not understanding how to retrieve.

here is the code:

```
<?php

function pairstr2Arr ($str, $separator='=', $delim=',') {
    $elems = explode($delim, $str);
    foreach( $elems as $elem => $val ) {
        $val = trim($val);
        $nameVal[] = explode($separator, $val);
        $arr[trim(strtolower($nameVal[$elem][0]))] = trim($nameVal[$elem][1]);
    }
        return $arr;
}

//  Example usage:
$string = 'uid=john,ou=grp1,ou=people,dc=site,dc=com';
$array = pairstr2Arr($string);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

output:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [uid] => john
    [ou] => people //here I want to get output ou=grp1,how?
    [dc] => com
)
</pre>
```

find output here: `https://ideone.com/rE6eaH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `ou` and `dc` might have multiple values, you should store those values in array. Thanks to that you can have easy access to data. Check out this code:

```
<?php

function pairstr2Arr ($str, $separator='=', $delim=',') {
    $elems = explode($delim, $str);

    $arr = array();
    foreach( $elems as $elem => $val ) {
        $val = trim($val);
        $tempArray = explode($separator, $val);

        if(!isset($arr[trim($tempArray[0])]))
            $arr[trim($tempArray[0])] = '';

        $arr[trim($tempArray[0])] .= $tempArray[1].';'; 
    }

    foreach($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        $explodedValue = explode(';', $value);
        if(count($explodedValue) > 2)
        {
            $arr[$key] = $explodedValue;
            unset($arr[$key][count($explodedValue) - 1]);
        }
        else
            $arr[$key] = substr($arr[$key], 0, -1);
    }
    return $arr;
}

//  Example usage:
$string = 'uid=john,ou=grp1,ou=people,dc=site,dc=com';
$array = pairstr2Arr($string);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Result is:

```
Array
(
    [uid] => john
    [ou] => Array
        (
            [0] => grp1
            [1] => people
        )

    [dc] => Array
        (
            [0] => site
            [1] => com
        )
)
```